# Query headers added to cmake project

Tags: cmake

I would like to get all headers added to cmake project.  The use case is that I'd get this list of headers and call some custom validation on them.  I would really love this to be a query mechanism to mitigate errors in oversight.

I am not interested in globbing the file system as headers may exist that are not appropriate for every platform.  It's also bad.

This is what I would like the usage to look like.

```
add_library(example_lib
    foo.h
    foo.cpp
    bar.h
    bar.cpp
)

add_executable(example main_example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example example_lib)

# this is the feature I am interested in
get_target_headers(example_header example)

# alternatively
get_target_headers(example_header example example_lib)

do_custom_thing("${example_header}")
```

A more manual way of doing this would be something like the below.  I'd just reuse the `example_header` variable to do the custom validation.

```
set(example_header
    foo.h
    bar.h
)

set(example_source
    foo.cpp
    bar.cpp
)

add_library(example_lib
    ${example_header}
    ${example_source}
)

add_executable(example main_example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example example_lib)

do_custom_thing("${example_header}")
```

This is what I'm doing now and it works, I am just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Normally I do it like your second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your headers have a ".h" suffix, you could use something like:

```
function(get_target_headers Headers MainTarget)
  # Gather list of MainTarget's dependencies
  get_target_property(Dependencies ${MainTarget} LINK_LIBRARIES)
  set(AllTargets ${MainTarget})
  foreach(Dependency ${Dependencies})
    # If this is a CMake target, add it to the list
    if(TARGET ${Dependency})
      list(APPEND AllTargets ${Dependency})
    endif()
  endforeach()

  # Gather each target's list of source files ending in ".h"
  foreach(Target ${AllTargets})
    get_target_property(Sources ${Target} SOURCES)
    foreach(Source ${Sources})
      string(REGEX MATCH "^.*\\.h$" Header ${Source})
      if(Header)
        list(APPEND AllHeaders ${Header})
      endif()
    endforeach()
  endforeach()

  # Since functions have their own scope, set the list in the parent scope
  set(${Headers} ${AllHeaders} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

and invoke it using your first choice:

```
get_target_headers(example_header example)
```

Comment: Would this pull in external dependencies?  Things like boost headers for instance?  I'm having issues finding where all the various properties that `get_target_property` supports.

Comment: It'll only work for actual CMake targets, i.e. things added via `add_library`, `add_executable`, etc.  So if boost is included via `find_package` it won't work for boost.

Comment: The list of properties that apply to targets is documented [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#section_PropertiesonTargets)

Comment: got a chance to test it finally, working well. thanks for the link too!